# Post a form once valid?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Im using vee validate on my inputs, to prevent the form submitting I use:

```
<form action="/place-to-post-to" @submit.prevent="$validator.validateAll()">
```

When the form validates, the form does not post. How can I make it post to the action once its valid?

Comment: You use "@submit.prevent" so the form is never submitted because ".prevent" prevent the form to submit. You can use @submit="$validator.validateAll( $event )" and inside your method you do validateAll( event ){ if( !isValid ){ event.preventDefault }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `validateAll()` in a method and on success, submit the form yourself.

```
<form action="/path/to/action" method="post" @submit.prevent="onSubmit" ref="theForm">

methods:{
    onSubmit(){
      this.$validator.validateAll()
        .then(() =>{
          this.$refs.theForm.submit()
        })
        .catch((error) =>{
          console.log(error)
        })
    }
}
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/XMxjmK?editors=1010).